# Ansible and Jinja2 logic for loops

Tags: ansible, jinja2, ansible-template

Variable file `createuser`:

```
    userslist:
      - da_cel_upload
      - da_tag_upload
```

Ansible logic:

```
    - include_vars: group_vars/createuser


    - name: Create custom file /etc/ssh/shhd_config for user configuration and restart sshd service
      template: src=sshconfig.j2 dest=/etc/ssh/sshd_config
      with_items: '{{userslist}}'
      notify: restart ssh
```

Contents of `sshconfig.j2`:

```
    Match User {{ item }}
    {% raw %}ChrootDirectory /home/{% endraw %}{{ item }}
    X11Forwarding no
    AllowTcpForwarding no
    ForceCommand internal-sftp
```

Output I get in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`:

```
    Match User da_tag_upload
    ChrootDirectory /home/da_tag_upload
    X11Forwarding no
    AllowTcpForwarding no
    ForceCommand internal-sftp
```

Output I need:

```
    Match User da_cel_upload
    ChrootDirectory /home/da_tag_upload
    X11Forwarding no
    AllowTcpForwarding no
    ForceCommand internal-sftp

    Match User da_tag_upload
    ChrootDirectory /home/da_tag_upload
    X11Forwarding no
    AllowTcpForwarding no
    ForceCommand internal-sftp
```

Please help.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please have a look at the [guides for asking questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking), specifically [how to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to move the loop to inside of the Jinja2 template instead of Ansible's `with_items` (which causes the `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` file to be overwritten in each subsequent iteration).

So the task:

```
- name: Create custom file /etc/ssh/shhd_config for user configuration and restart sshd service
  template:
    src: sshconfig.j2
    dest: /etc/ssh/sshd_config
  notify: restart ssh
```

And the template (essentially the same as in the question, but wrapped in `for`-loop):

```
{% for item in userslist %}
Match User {{ item }}
{% raw %}ChrootDirectory /home/{% endraw %}{{ item }}
X11Forwarding no
AllowTcpForwarding no
ForceCommand internal-sftp
{% endfor %}
```

<sup>Add blank line to the end to get the exact output to need. SO does not display dangling blank lines.</sup>